# Tree view by default in Inventory

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In Sales when I go to Product menu I get tree view by default.
I did it like this

```xml
<record id="product.product_normal_action_sell" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form,kanban</field>
        </record>
        <record id="product.product_template_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form,kanban</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
        </record>
```

Same in Purchase and Manufacturing but I have a problem to do the same in Inventory.

This is an original menu that calls an action

```xml
<menuitem
            action="product.product_template_action_product" id="menu_product_variant_config_stock" name="Products"
            parent="stock.menu_stock_inventory_control" sequence="1"/>
```

how can I make it that when I go to Inventory->Products tree view opens by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's the same. you need to add

```xml
  <record id="product.product_template_action_product" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form,kanban</field>
        </record>
```

to Product view